# Exception order Magento 2

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, orders

I face a problem with my magento 2 orders, i've migrated my website from Magento 1.9 to Magento 2.1.7 but there is some magento 1.9 order that i can't open, i've this error "exeption during loading order informations" and this go back to the list of all orders, i've seen some few persons with the same problem but none of their solutions worked for me :/ My new website is live and there is some orders that i can't send because of this problem.

Update: I can see all amazon order from Magento 1.9 but not the order from my website.

If someone know the solution it'll be apreciate to know what i need to do :)

Comment: check the customer information for those order. That may cause the issue.

Comment: What do you mean by this ?

Comment: Customer information means customer email,name,dob etc

Comment: Yes i know but what of this can make this problem appear ? this is not on all magento 1 orders

Comment: open  vendor/magento/module-sales/view/adminhtml/templates/order/view/info.phtml and looks for $block->getCustomerAccountData(). commant that part and try to open the order to check if this is causing the issue or not.

Comment: when i go to vendor/magento i only have "composer" "magento-composer-installer" and "zendframework1" that's strange

Comment: look at app/code/Magento

Comment: i've commented and the problem is still here  :/

Comment: Have you commented this part completely                     <?php foreach ($block->getCustomerAccountData() as $data):?>
                        <tr>
                            <th><?= $block->escapeHtml($data['label']) ?></th>
                            <td><?= $block->escapeHtml($data['value'], ['br']) ?></td>
                        </tr>
                    <?php endforeach;?>

Comment: yes with <!-- -->

Comment: After commenting have you checked error? I have faced the same issue by commenting this way. because of php short tag, this may cause issue.

Comment: yes after commented i've cleaned cache and tested if the order was able to display but still not and the error is the same :/

Comment: Hi, there is no other way to fix it ?

Comment: Please debug the code and  find out the section which causing  the issue.

Comment: i've commented each one of date required in the info.phtml one by one and tested it and there was no change the error is still here.

Comment: i can see magento 1.9 order that are from amazon but no the other one made on my site

Comment: i've tried to put the info.phtml from an other magento version but problem is still here :(